# mysqli quickest way to post only one result

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

I wonder if it's possible to do the following script without so much params and strings... I think there is much that can be removed... Maybe with only one query?

Thank you!

```
<?php
include("sqlvar.php");

$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
$marginidb = $connection->query("SELECT valore FROM DATIVENDITA WHERE parametro = 'margine'");
while($margine = $marginidb->fetch_object()) {
        $valoremargine = $margine->valore;
}
$connection->close();

echo $valoremargine;

$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
$ivadb = $connection->query("SELECT valore FROM DATIVENDITA WHERE parametro = 'iva'");
while($iva = $ivadb->fetch_object()) {
        $valoreiva = $iva->valore;
}
$connection->close();

echo $valoreiva;
?>
```

Comment: you could use fetch_row instead of fetch_object, so you can get rid of the while loop. And dont close your connection if you are going to use the same connection later, let PHP handle that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think you're asking for:

```
<?php
include("sqlvar.php");
$result = array();
$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
$marginidb = $connection->query("SELECT valore FROM DATIVENDITA WHERE parametro = 'margine' OR parametro = 'iva'");
while($margine = $marginidb->fetch_object()) {
        array_push($result, $margine->valore);
}
$connection->close();
print_r($result);
?>
```

What this does is stores the results as an array so to access the first result you would use `$result[0]` and the second would be `$result[1]`. You could loop thro these results using a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted!

Comment: I just want to note that using a single query there is no way to distinguish which between "margine" and "iva". You do not know which will come out first from the database.

Comment: then this is a problem... Isn't it fixed wich comes first?
If I have an id column with auto increment?

Comment: If you use the ID column to sort, then yes, this might help. But, it will only help if you are assured that "margine" is always in the database before "iva". From a development standpoint, this is a bad way to do things. You should never make assumptions like this. This is a very bad pattern that can lead to problems much later when people forget about the odd details. I believe you were going a better direction with two different queries.

Comment: margine and iva are in a fixed column called parametri that will be never changed. Only the value in valore will be changed. So margine will always have id 1 and iva always id 2!

Comment: I think this will work well:
SELECT valore FROM `DATIVENDITA` ORDER BY id ASC

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include("sqlvar.php");

$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);

$marginidb = $connection->query("SELECT valore FROM DATIVENDITA WHERE parametro = 'margine' limit 1");
$margine = $marginidb->fetch_object();
echo $margine->valore;

$ivadb = $connection->query("SELECT valore FROM DATIVENDITA WHERE parametro = 'iva' limit 1");
$iva = $ivadb->fetch_object();
echo $iva->valore;

$connection->close();

?>
```

Comment: thank you! If I want to print the 2 params in two separate places?
E.g. value of margine at the top of the page and value of iva at the bottom?

Comment: If you need to distinguish between the two, then you probably should have two different queries. I will rewrite it again.

Comment: thank but C1D has replied my question! With array_push it's perfect!